# how to save output from C++ function, to python variable

Tags: python

I already have working function in my python script from C++ using boost.

This function is printing me some data (string) 
To call this function I am using this code:

```
import cpp as cpp_fun #importing from c++ already compiled with boost (no exe)
file = path_to_file #doesn't matter which file
cpp_fun.strings(file)#gives me output
output:
"this is test string, one line of many.."
```

I dont even need to use `print(cpp_fun.strings())` to print output, so problem is,
that I cant add it to variable, and then print this variable, because this function is printing output all the time when I run python.

I want to save output from `cpp_fun.strings()` to variable
but when I am doing :

```
strings = cpp_fun.strings()
```

It gives me output again...

I've tried to create method (`def()`) and put this function inside , but  with the same result after all, 
also i have tried to catch output:

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
new_stdout = StringIO()
sys.stdout = new_stdout
print(cp_fun.strings())
output = new_stdout.getvalue()
sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

But without success, this catch above is working for normal print but not for this one.
I've tried also add `var=subprocess.check_output([cpp_fun])` -not working
Maybe you have any ideas how to save it to variable?

Comment: Do you have the option of modifying the C++ code?  Having it return a value, rather than printing directly to STDOUT, would be by far the simplest solution.

Comment: Thats the point, i cant modify it:(

Comment: Then running the code in a subprocess seems to be the only possible solution.  Please supply more detail on your attempt than "no success".

Comment: I tried only add ‘var=subprocess.check_output([cpp_fun])’

Comment: That's not running it in a subprocess, that's trying to treat it as a name of a program to run in a subprocess.  You need two actual programs to do this, only the inner one will import & run the C++ code.

Comment: @ jasonharper thanks, could you provide an example how to use subprocess here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced your *cpp* extension module by a plain *Python* one, which simply prints every line of the file that it receives as an argument. 
Below it's an example of capturing its output.

*cpp.py*:

```py
def strings(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line.rstrip())
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import io
import traceback

import cpp as cpp_fun


def capture_function_output(func, *func_args):
    tmp_buf_out = io.StringIO()
    tmp_buf_err = io.StringIO()
    _sys_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = tmp_buf_out
    _sys_stderr = sys.stderr
    sys.stderr = tmp_buf_err
    try:
        func_ret = func(*func_args)
    except:
        func_ret = None
        traceback.print_exc()
    tmp_buf_out.flush()
    tmp_buf_err.flush()
    sys.stdout = _sys_stdout
    sys.stderr = _sys_stderr
    tmp_buf_out.seek(0)
    func_stdout = tmp_buf_out.read()
    tmp_buf_err.seek(0)
    func_stderr = tmp_buf_err.read()
    return func_ret, func_stdout, func_stderr


def test_capture_cpp_fun_output(file_name):
    retcode, sout, serr = capture_function_output(cpp_fun.strings, file_name)  # Store function return code, stdout and stderr contents into 3 variables
    print("Function ({0:s}) returned: {1:}".format(cpp_fun.strings.__name__, retcode))
    print("Function printed to stdout: \n{0:s}".format(sout))
    print("--- Done")
    print("Function printed to stderr: \n{0:s}".format(serr))
    print("--- Done")


def main(*argv):
    for file_name in [
        "dummy.txt",
        "dummy.txt0",  # Doesn't exist!
    ]:
        print("\nTesting file: {0:s}:".format(file_name))
        test_capture_cpp_fun_output(file_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q060851454>sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> type dummy.txt
> dummy line 0
> next line
> 0123456789
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
>
> Testing file: dummy.txt:
> Function (strings) returned: None
> Function printed to stdout:
> dummy line 0
> next line
> 0123456789
>
> --- Done
> Function printed to stderr:
>
> --- Done
>
> Testing file: dummy.txt0:
> Function (strings) returned: None
> Function printed to stdout:
>
> --- Done
> Function printed to stderr:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code00.py", line 18, in capture_function_output
>     func_ret = func(*func_args)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q060851454\cpp.py", line 2, in strings
>     with open(file_name) as f:
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dummy.txt0'
>
> --- Done
>
> Done.
> ```

---

#### Update *#0*

Changed the code to also capture function's *stderr*.

---

#### Update *#1*

Adding the [[Python 3.Docs]: subprocess - Subprocess management](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) based variant (which works too on my side). This needs an additional script (*cpp_wrapper.py*, which relies on *cpp.py* from above).

*cpp_wrapper.py*:

```py
import sys

import cpp as cpp_fun


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
        raise RuntimeError("Missing argument")
    file_name = sys.argv[1]
    try:
        cpp_fun.strings(file_name)
    except:
        raise
else:
    raise RuntimeError("This module should be executed directly")
```

*code01.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import subprocess


def capture_cpp_fun_output(file_name):
    cmd = (sys.executable, "cpp_wrapper.py", file_name)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    return p.returncode, out.decode(), err.decode()


def main(*argv):
    for file_name in [
        "dummy.txt",
        "dummy.txt0",  # Doesn't exist!
    ]:
        print("\nTesting file: {0:s}:".format(file_name))
        retcode, sout, serr = capture_cpp_fun_output(file_name)  # Store function return code, stdout and stderr contents into 3 variables
        print("Function returned: {0:}".format(retcode))
        print("Function printed to stdout: \n{0:s}".format(sout))
        print("--- Done")
        print("Function printed to stderr: \n{0:s}".format(serr))
        print("--- Done")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code01.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
>
> Testing file: dummy.txt:
> Function returned: 0
> Function printed to stdout:
> dummy line 0
> next line
> 0123456789
>
> --- Done
> Function printed to stderr:
>
> --- Done
>
> Testing file: dummy.txt0:
> Function returned: 1
> Function printed to stdout:
>
> --- Done
> Function printed to stderr:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "cpp_wrapper.py", line 11, in <module>
>     cpp_fun.strings(file_name)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q060851454\cpp.py", line 2, in strings
>     with open(file_name) as f:
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dummy.txt0'
>
> --- Done
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately it's not working, but i will investigate it more.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? How is it behaving? Could it be that the *.dll* is outputting text on *stderr*?

Comment: i am receiving output, but i still cant catch it to variable

Comment: I modified the answer so that the *stderr* is captured as well. Perhaps you might want ti give that a shot.

Comment: now its better, output finally stops printing, now i need to figure out how to store it to variable, and then i finally can analyze it

Comment: But I already did that. You need to copy *capture\_function\_output* verbatim, and in *test\_capture\_cpp\_fun\_output* I assigned the output to the *serr* variable (which I printed 2 lines below). What's left there to analyze?

Comment: my output looks like this one:
`Testing file: 'D:\file':
Function (strings) returned: None
Function printed to stdout: 

--- Done
Function printed to stderr: 

--- Done

Done.`
it seems stderr not see function output or i am wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210429/discussion-between-cristifati-and-sygneto).